# How to handle big and small data in amCharts

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am working with Column Chart (amCharts). When I put data like 10352, 40, 103,  1 etc. I only see 10352 column. I know there is an option in google charts called logScale, which handles the small and big data. Is there any similar option in amCharts?

Answer (score 0):

To turn on logarithmic scale for a value axis in amCharts use its [`logarithmic`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#logarithmic) property. I.e.:

```
"valueAxes": [{
  "logarithmic": true
}]
```

Here's an example at amcharts.com that uses logarithmic scale to display dramatically different values in scale:

http://www.amcharts.com/demos/logarithmic-scale/